# How to use autofill otp like google's one-tap SMS verification with the SMS User Consent API in React Native

Tags: react-native, sms-verification

I'm trying to achieve phone number verification with the autofill feature in React native application. So far, I've discovered that there are 2 ways i.e either append hash key in sms body or use SMS User Consent API like https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/user-consent/overview

Is there any way/library through which we can avoid using the hash key?